# Deleting rows without checking foreign indexes, triggers, etc in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is referenced by 11 other tables as foreign key constraint. If I try to delete a row from it, apparently it checks the other tables to see if it should cascade delete other records, which is making the delete take too long. I've tried disabling constraints in the table I'm deleting and the other tables but it's not working (on the results panel I still get 11 lines of "0 rows affected").

I've already deleted the children, what should I so it doesn't go on these tables to check for cascades? Here's how I've been testing this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE Table1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    ALTER TABLE Table2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

    DELETE FROM Table2 
    WHERE id IN (100, 101)

    ALTER TABLE Table2 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    ALTER TABLE Table1 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: "it's not working" - care to share the error message?

Comment: Not an actual error. If the disables were working, I imagine the result panel wouldn't show the "0 rows affected" for the other tables.

Comment: Stupid question: Is there any record for id =100,101?

Answer (score 0):

BTW: You are in pretty dangerous position of breaking data integrity. Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE C1(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
GO
INSERT INTO C1 DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10
GO
SELECT * INTO C2 FROM C1;
GO
ALTER TABLE C2 WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C12 FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES C1 (ID);
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT is_not_trusted from sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'FK_C12';
    ALTER TABLE C1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    ALTER TABLE C2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    DELETE FROM C1 WHERE ID = 5;
    ALTER TABLE C2 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    ALTER TABLE C1 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    SELECT is_not_trusted from sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'FK_C12';
ROLLBACK
```

[image]
That means after your FK is not trusted anymore you might come up with different/slower execution plans and an additional and maybe unnecessary I/O